# cakephp multiple ajax request session problems

Tags: ajax, session, cakephp

I have a problem with the handling of sessions in Cakephp. I make two request. The first request submits a form and many things happens. The second request is an ajax-request that want to get to know the status of the first request.
Therefor I write the status into a session variable. I google a lot and I know it's possible that I get a valid return for each ajax-status-request. The problem is, that the variable in the session is always the last status of the request before. Here an example:

Frist submit

Ajax-Status-Request 1: status 1

Ajax-Status-Request 2: status 1

...

Ajax-Status-Request 10: status 1

End (status should be 10)

Second submit

Ajax-Status-Request 1: status 10

Ajax-Status-Request 2: status 10

...

Ajax-Status-Request 10: status 10

End (status should be 10)

In cakephp i tried to configure 'php' and 'cake'. But if I use this configuration each ajax-request was waiting until the submit was finished. Now i tried "cache".

```
    Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'cache'
));
```

*Controller of the form submit*

```
$this->Session->write('request_status', "start");
sleep(5);
for($i =1;$i<500000;$i++){
    if($i == 1000){
        $this->Session->write('request_status', $this->Session->read('request_status').$i);
    }
    if($i == 7000){
        $this->Session->write('request_status', $this->Session->read('request_status').$i);
    }
}
$this->Session->write('request_status', "ende");
```

*Ajax-status-request*

```
public function checkRequestStatus(){
    $this->respond($this->Session->read('request_status'), true);
}
```

*Ajax-Code*

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'AjaxRequestStatus','action'=> 'checkRequestStatus', 'plugin' => ''));?>",
            async: false,
            success: function(data){
                $('#popup_content').append(data+ "<br />");
            }
         });
```

Ok, I expect that also other people was able to create a multiple request and want to get know the status of the first request. What is my mistake? Is it a configuration problem?

Greetz

V

Comment: Incomplete question, show 2 ajax code?

Comment: I added the Ajax-code but i think i should be not that interesting because the problem is the value or access to the session.

Comment: this is one ajax where is second? and also tell the security level of session in core file, type also.

Comment: it's the second one. The first request is a normal form submit. Is it important that both requests are ajax-requests?